# some elements are not removed from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have created an array for vowels position in string now i want reomve all elements that have value -1 from this array but its not working

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowelp=[];
  var newarr=str.split('');
   vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('a'));
   vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('e'));
   vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('i'));
   vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('o'));
   vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('u'));
   var minvowel=vowelp[0];
for(var i=0;i<vowelp.length;i++) {   //looping through vowel's position array
    if(vowelp[i]==-1)  {
   vowelp.splice(i,1);
      console.log(vowelp[i]);
      }
  }
  return vowelp;
}
```

input-translatePigLatin("consonant");
output that i am getting is[6,-1,1] but i want [6,1]

Comment: What about looping backwards: `for (var i = vowelp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @Shubham - what are you passing as str?

Comment: translatePigLatin("consonant");

Comment: When you call `splice` and remove a -1, `i` points to the next element, which gets ignored because of `i++`

Comment: I refer the gentleman to my first comment. https://jsfiddle.net/oemt103q/

Comment: @Andy its working thanks

Comment: @Jae thanks for explanation

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is to use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowelp = [];
  var newarr = str.split('');
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('a'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('e'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('i'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('o'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('u'));
  var minvowel = vowelp[0];
  return vowelp.filter(function(v) {
    return v != -1;
  })
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant"));
```

---

In your case you need to decrement the value of `i` in case of item removal otherwise it will skip the next element.

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowelp = [];
  var newarr = str.split('');
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('a'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('e'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('i'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('o'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('u'));
  var minvowel = vowelp[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < vowelp.length; i++) { //looping through vowel's position array
    if (vowelp[i] == -1) {
      vowelp.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
      console.log(vowelp[i]);
    }
  }
  return vowelp;
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant"));
```

---

You can make it more simple using **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** with an array

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].map(function(v) {
    return str.indexOf(v);
  }).filter(function(v) {
    return v != -1;
  });
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant"));
```

Comment: its working.but why mine is not working

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `splice` on the same `array` you are iterating over. Rememeber splice is mutable and it deletes from the original array. As a result of that your index tracking logic is getting messed up. So instead you could use `delete[i]` (which does not mess up the indexes and creates a void)

```
 function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowelp=[];
  var newarr=str.split('');
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('a'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('e'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('i'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('o'));
  vowelp.push(newarr.indexOf('u'));
  var minvowel=vowelp[0];
  for(var i=0;i<vowelp.length;i++) {   //looping through vowel's position array
    if(vowelp[i]==-1)  {
        delete vowelp[i];
    }
  }
  return vowelp;
}


  console.log(translatePigLatin("consonant")); //prints [6, 3: 1]
```

which means you have `6` at `index 0` and `1` at `index 3`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a simpler code:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowelp = [];
  var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
  for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    var index = str.indexOf(vowels[i]);
    if (index != -1) {
        vowelp.push(index);
    }
  }
  return vowelp;
}
```